# Facebook user email is not getting

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have a problem.I'm changing my operation system from windows to ubunty. Before it I made commit all project to bitbacket.Download it on new system later import in eclipse(ubunty).Start my app and tried login with facebook and get user email address and get null pointer.
I'm also remove old facebook app and install new one.

there is my peace of code.Can someone help me?

```
 private String[] permissions = new String[]{ "email"};
 private LoginButton mFacebookLoginButton;

  mFacebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions( permissions );


 @Override
  public void onCompleted( GraphUser user, Response response )
  {
    if( null != user )
    {
      mUserInfo = new UserInfo();
      mUserInfo.userEmail = user.getProperty( "email" ).toString();

      mUserInfo.userName = user.getName();
      mUserInfo.firstName = user.getFirstName();
      mUserInfo.lastName = user.getLastName();
      mUserInfo.facebookId = user.getId();
      mUserInfo.hassPassword = 0;

      RegisterDevice regDevice = new RegisterDevice( getActivity() );
      regDevice.setStoreDeviceId( this );
      regDevice.execute();
    }
  }
```

in my  log was messages like this

```
    07-14 18:46:08.593: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.facebook.pages.app.provider.ACCESS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:46:08.593: W/PackageManager(774): Not granting permission android.permission.BATTERY_STATS to package com.facebook.katana (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x88be44)
07-14 18:46:08.593: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:46:08.593: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:46:08.593: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:46:08.593: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:46:08.593: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:46:08.593: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission .home.permission.WRITE_BADGES in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:46:08.593: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.nokia.pushnotifications.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:46:08.593: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:47:45.613: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.facebook.pages.app.provider.ACCESS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:47:45.613: W/PackageManager(774): Not granting permission android.permission.BATTERY_STATS to package com.facebook.katana (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x88be44)
07-14 18:47:45.613: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:47:45.613: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:47:45.613: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:47:45.613: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:47:45.623: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:47:45.623: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission .home.permission.WRITE_BADGES in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:47:45.623: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.nokia.pushnotifications.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:47:45.623: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:48:44.393: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.facebook.pages.app.provider.ACCESS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:48:44.393: W/PackageManager(774): Not granting permission android.permission.BATTERY_STATS to package com.facebook.katana (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x88be44)
07-14 18:48:44.393: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:48:44.393: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:48:44.393: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:48:44.393: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:48:44.393: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:48:44.393: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission .home.permission.WRITE_BADGES in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:48:44.393: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.nokia.pushnotifications.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:48:44.393: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:50:18.323: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.facebook.pages.app.provider.ACCESS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:50:18.323: W/PackageManager(774): Not granting permission android.permission.BATTERY_STATS to package com.facebook.katana (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x88be44)
07-14 18:50:18.323: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:50:18.323: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:50:18.323: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:50:18.323: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:50:18.323: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:50:18.323: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission .home.permission.WRITE_BADGES in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:50:18.323: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.nokia.pushnotifications.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:50:18.323: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:54:34.903: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.facebook.pages.app.provider.ACCESS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:54:34.903: W/PackageManager(774): Not granting permission android.permission.BATTERY_STATS to package com.facebook.katana (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x88be44)
07-14 18:54:34.903: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:54:34.903: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:54:34.903: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:54:34.903: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:54:34.903: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:54:34.903: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission .home.permission.WRITE_BADGES in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:54:34.903: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.nokia.pushnotifications.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:54:34.903: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 18:58:22.553: I/ActivityManager(774): START u0 {cmp=com.facebook.katana/.ProxyAuth (has extras)} from pid 9085
07-14 18:58:22.573: I/ActivityManager(774): START u0 {cmp=com.facebook.katana/.ProxyAuthDialog (has extras)} from pid 7227
07-14 19:03:45.063: I/ActivityManager(774): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE dat=package:com.facebook.katana cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.UninstallerActivity (has extras)} from pid 31047
07-14 19:03:46.023: I/ActivityManager(774): Force stopping com.facebook.katana appid=10086 user=-1: uninstall pkg
07-14 19:03:46.023: I/ActivityManager(774): Killing 7227:com.facebook.katana/u0a86 (adj 13): stop com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:03:46.023: W/ActivityManager(774): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.push.mqtt.service.MqttPushService in 1000ms
07-14 19:03:46.023: I/ActivityManager(774): Killing 7490:com.facebook.katana:dash/u0a86 (adj 15): stop com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:03:46.033: I/ActivityManager(774):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{433b8f88 u0 com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.push.mqtt.service.MqttPushService}
07-14 19:03:46.143: W/PackageManager(774): Couldn't delete native library directory /data/app-lib/com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:03:46.143: I/PackageManager(774): Removing old permission: com.facebook.receiver.permission.ACCESS from package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:03:46.143: I/PackageManager(774): Removing old permission: com.facebook.katana.permission.C2D_MESSAGE from package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:03:46.143: I/PackageManager(774): Removing old permission: com.facebook.katana.permission.CROSS_PROCESS_BROADCAST_MANAGER from package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:03:46.143: I/PackageManager(774): Removing old permission: com.facebook.permission.debug.SYSTEM_COMMUNICATION from package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:03:46.143: I/PackageManager(774): Removing old permission: com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS from package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:03:46.143: I/PackageManager(774): Removing old permission: com.facebook.katana.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE from package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:03:46.143: I/PackageManager(774): Removing old permission: com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION from package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:03:46.153: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS in package com.facebook.orca
07-14 19:03:46.233: I/ActivityManager(774): Force stopping com.facebook.katana appid=10086 user=0: pkg removed
07-14 19:03:46.523: D/BackupManagerService(774): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.facebook.katana flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
07-14 19:03:46.793: W/PackageManager(774): Package named 'com.facebook.katana' doesn't exist.
07-14 19:04:13.453: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.facebook.katana.provider.ACCESS in package com.facebook.orca
07-14 19:04:29.003: I/ActivityManager(774): START u0 {act=com.google.android.finsky.NAVIGATIONAL_SUGGESTION dat=https://market.android.com/details?id=com.facebook.katana&feature=sugg flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.vending/.AssetBrowserActivity (has extras)} from pid 20908
07-14 19:04:40.583: W/ActivityManager(774): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/data/com.android.vending/cache/gzipped/com.facebook.katana141515487.apk
07-14 19:04:40.753: W/ActivityManager(774): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/data/com.android.vending/cache/gzipped/com.facebook.katana141515487.apk
07-14 19:04:46.333: W/PackageManager(774): Package com.facebook.katana desires unavailable shared library com.amazon.device.messaging; ignoring!
07-14 19:04:48.883: I/ActivityManager(774): Force stopping com.facebook.katana appid=10101 user=-1: update pkg
07-14 19:04:48.983: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.facebook.pages.app.provider.ACCESS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:04:48.983: W/PackageManager(774): Not granting permission android.permission.BATTERY_STATS to package com.facebook.katana (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x8be44)
07-14 19:04:48.983: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:04:48.983: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:04:48.983: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:04:48.983: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:04:48.983: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:04:48.983: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission .home.permission.WRITE_BADGES in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:04:48.983: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.nokia.pushnotifications.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:04:48.983: W/PackageManager(774): Unknown permission com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE in package com.facebook.katana
07-14 19:04:49.283: D/BackupManagerService(774): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.facebook.katana flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your apps page on facebook and add there your new key hash. It changed, because your debug.keystore changed (because you switched to Ubuntu).